# quantile regression with e.g. gamma distribution and log link

Tags: generalized-linear-model, quantile-regression

I have a basic question about quantile regression (I'm new to it):
Why doesn't it seem possible to do a quantile regression with a specified family (e.g. gamma) and link function (e.g. log), as in a glm? Or if it is possible, is there an R package that can do this? I've looked over the internet but no such thing seems to exist and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A link function is in principle possible in quantile regression. For example, here is an article that discusses quantile regression with a logit link function: http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0231 I don't know whether this has been implemented in R, as I don't use R often enough to say anything meaningful about it. There are many R users on this list, so let's hope they chime in.

A family does not make sense for quantile regression, as it would not use any "information" from that assumption anyhow in its estimates. So any family you would specify would result in exactly the same numbers.